# Call variable class with PHP without call_user_func

Tags: php, oop, class

Is there a way to call a function in a class without using 'call_user_func' and without eval?

here is why I ask:

When I use 'call_user_func' I get the '$this not in context' error:

```
$this->id = $selectId['id'];
$file = 'score_' . $this->sid . '.php'; //the file with the class

if (@include_once($file)) { //including the file

    $scoreClass = 'Score_' . $this->id;
    call_user_func($scoreClass .'::selectData', $this->user_id);
}
```

I can overcome this 'not in context' error calling the function like this:
but now my name is not variable.

```
$this->id = $selectId['id'];
$file = 'score_' . $this->sid . '.php'; //the file with the class

if (@include_once($file)) { //including the file

    $test = new Score_98673();
    $test->selectData($this->user_id);

}
```

Comment: [Static methods are not in an object-context](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) *"Because static methods are callable without an instance of the object created, the pseudo-variable $this is not available inside the method declared as static."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (@include_once($file)) { //including the file
    $scoreClass = 'Score_' . $this->id;
    $test = new $scoreClass();
    $test->selectData($this->user_id);
}
```

This is all you have to do. As you can use variable class names when using `new`.

The above fails as you call a non-static method (should throw some error) which uses `$this`.

Answer (score 3):

```
call_user_func(array($score, 'selectData'), $this->user_id);
```

This is the correct syntax for the `callable` pseudotype.
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php

You can also do this, BTW:

```
$method = 'selectData';
$score->$method($this->user_id);
```

Comment: Don't forget to indicate that he can instantiate the class with `$class = new $scoreClass;`

Comment: When I use the first example I still get: "Using $this when not in object context"  When I use the second example I will get this error: "Call to a member function selectPDFData() on a non-object"

Comment: @Boni `$score` will of course have to be an *instance* of the class, an object. Without instantiating an object you cannot call instance methods on it. In your example that's `$test`.